# Frustum culling + instancing

Tags: directx11, instancing, frustum-culling

I've implemented `instancing` in my app and right now I have an instance buffer holding position data for all instances. But I'd like to also implement `frustum culling` which would cull some of the instances depending on the camera view. Now, how can I render only some of the instances in the buffer but not all? Do I have to rebuild the buffer every frame (so that it only holds visible instances) or is there a way in `DirectX 11` to "tell" API which instances from the buffer I want drawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to do it would be to rebuild the instance buffer each frame, akin to a particle system or other dynamic vertex buffer.